# Need an explanation of the following proof

Tags: abstract-algebra

Every group G of order pq, where p and q are primes, is solvable

Proof if $p=q$ then G is a p-subgroup and solvable by Remark 13.2(b). So we can assume from now on, without loss of generality, that $p<q$. By sylo'w third theorem we know that $n_q(G)$ divides p and that $n_q(G) \equiv 1 mod q$. This implies that $n_q(G)=1$ and that G has a normal Sylow q-subgroups S. This leads to a subnormal series ${1_G} \lhd S \lhd G$ with factors of order q and order p. This implies the factors are abelian, and that G is solvable.

I don't understand the part that says "with factors of order q and order p". How do we know that the factors have these orders

Comment: S is a q Sylow subgroup and has order q. Hence the quotient group $S:1_G$ has order q. $G$ has order $pq$ and $S$ is normal subgroup of  order $q$ and hence quotient group $G:S$ has order $p$.

Answer (score 1):

The Sylow q-subgroup S has order q (by definition of being a q-Sylow). For this subnormal series to be "good", i.e., for it to prove that $G$ is solvable, we need that $G/S$ and $S/1_G$ are abelian. The first group has order $pq/q = p$, while the second has order $q$. So these groups are cyclic groups and they are abelian.